# jquery wrap multiple td's in a form onclick

Tags: jquery, forms, append

What I'm trying to do is wrap `<form>` tags around all `<td>` using jquery when a button is clicked. So basically once the button is clicked, I want to turn this:

```
<tr>
  <td>cell 1</td>
  <td>cell 2</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="edit">edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

into this:

```
<tr>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="edit">edit</button></td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

I have tried using `insertBefore() / insertAfter()`, `wrap()`, `append()` and `before() / after()`

but they seem to either not work or append the full `<form method="post" action=""></form>`  before the first `<td>`. Here is an example of what I'm trying at the moment:

```
$("button.edit").click(function () {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').before('<form action="post">');
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last-child').after('</form>');
});
```

but as mentioned before it's not working properly. How can I go about appending the form tags to the correct place as mentioned before?

Comment: looks like invalid HTML what you are looking for

Comment: it is an invalid markup

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("button.edit").click(function () {
    var form = $('<form method="post" action="" />').append($('tr').children());
    $('tr').append(form);
});
```